# MVC Homecontroller edit details in DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

so just used a basic tutorial to make a DB and add new records to it. This all works fine...However now I would like to edit a record....

```
// GET: /Home/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "id")]MovieTable1 movieToCreate)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

           //so i need to insert a line of code here to say something like update
            //I was using the previous code:
           //_entities.AddToMovieTable1(movieToCreate);
            _entities.SaveChanges();           

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This isnt working I think all i have to do is edit the line '_entities.AddToMovieTable1(movieToCreate);' to something to edit the record

to get the add new record working ive used the code...

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private MoviesDBEntities _entities = new MoviesDBEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_entities.MovieTable1.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/Create

    [HttpPost]
    //public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "id")]MovieTable1 movieToCreate)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            _entities.AddToMovieTable1(movieToCreate);
            _entities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use:

```
_entities.Attach(moveiToModify);
_entities.Entry(moveiToModify).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I really dont know, why are you excluding the ID property, its required for the update.